# Yii2 debug panel + cloudlare

Tags: yii2, cloudflare

I have a trouble with my debug panel on production.
Since i turned on cloudflare my Yii2 debug panel disappeared because my $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is ip of cloudflare ns. How can i fix it?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
```

`$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]` is an extra variabel that is available with Cloudflare